# why i can't install cordova and ionic by command promt in window 8.1

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-2.0.0

I tried to install cordova and ionic by using command prompt. I have already installed the Nodejs. But it still show like below picture.Can you help me please I just start studying about this.Let see the picture!

[image]

Comment: verify `PATH` and retry

Comment: can you execute the following commands, please?
`npm -v`
`node -v`
`node -e "console.log('hello world')"`
Do they work?

Comment: yes i'll try to execute

Comment: it shows 3.10.10..what is it?

Answer (score 0):

First check node and npm versions

Node version

```
node -v
```

npm version

```
  npm -v
```

If they are showing versions without any problem you have successfully installed the node. then try to install cordova and ionic one by one.

First install the cordova

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

and then install ionic

```
sudo npm install -g ionic
```

Comment: if you are using windows just remove the sudo rest will work

Comment: what is your node and npm versions

Comment: i downloaded from nodejs.org v6.10.0 LTS   node (v6.10.0)  npm (3.10.10)

Comment: did you try using this way `npm install -g cordova`

Comment: If they work I will update my answer with extra code check it

Comment: node -v work but npm -v show 'prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command  operable program or batch file 3.10.10

Comment: use 4.4.2 instead n `npm install -g 4.4.2`

Comment: ok, then use `SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%` in command line and try again..

Comment: when i install nodejs, i have a problem near the end of installing..but it still show successful..is it because of my uncompleted installing?

Comment: it shows warning 1909. could not create shortcut Node.js command prompt.link. verify that the destination folder exists and thet you can access it

Comment: I guess maybe that is the issue try to do clean installation again.

Comment: it sill show warning 1909. could not create shortcut Node.js command prompt.link. verify that the destination folder exists and thet you can access it when reinstall nodejs..but when i click ok button ..it show successful

Comment: What is the path of your node installation?

Comment: C:\Program Files\nodejs\

Comment: Start > Run > %APPDATA% and then Create new folder name as  npm

Comment: thank you for replying! sorry i can't reply because my computer doesn't work..it still doesn't work

Comment: check npm is exist in %APPDATA% path, if exist then run your cordova and ionic installation commands

Comment: npm is empty inside

Comment: still the same to my problem before

Comment: when i install cordova it has  cordova folder  in  npm folder(auto generate)

Comment: I think it is better to uninstall your current node and install older one. this is a still open [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/8141). I am using node v4.4.1 (LTS) it is working well.

Comment: it still show the same problem...i think it doesn't cause the version of Nodejs...it maybe my computer but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: hmm, maybe I checked with node  v6.9.4 (LTS). It is also working. If any solution didn't work. Only thing you can do is re-setup you operating system.